# Почему не отображаются данные в таблице при использовании веб-сокетов для их передачи из сервера к клинту?

Tags: python, flask, websocket

Есть веб-приложение написанное с помощью Flask. В нем мне нужно передавать некоторые данные, рассчитанные алгоритмом, из сервера клиенту раз в 10 секунд, например. Раньше я делал это с помощью Ajax и все работало, но решил перейти на веб-сокеты. Проблема в том, что веб-сокеты работают нормально (по крайней мере, я не получаю никаких ошибок в консоли), но данные которые должны отображаться на html странице почему то не отображаются. Я использую библиотеку Flask SoketIO.

Серверный код:

```
@socketio.on('connect')
def handle_connect():
    print('Client connected')

@socketio.on('disconnect')
def handle_disconnect():
    print('Client disconnected')

@socketio.on('update_data')
def handle_send_data():
    data = func1()
    emit('update_data', data, broadcast=True)
```

script.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + '5000');

socket.on('update_data', function(response) {
    console.log('Received data:', response);
    var tableRows = "";
    $.each(response, function(index, item) {
        tableRows += "<tr><td>" + item.symbol + "</td><td><img src='" + item.logo + "' alt='Logo'></img>" + item.b + "</td><td>" + item.c + "</td><td><img src='" + item.d + "' alt='Logo'></img>" + item.e + "</td><td>" + item.f + "</td><td>" + item.g + "</td></tr>";
    });
    $("#data tbody").html(tableRows);
    $("#loading-message").css("display", "none");
});
```

});

В консоли браузера заметил следующие ошибки:

**Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.**

**Unchecked runtime.lastError: A listener indicated an asynchronous response by returning true, but the message channel closed before a response was received**

в консоли программы я заметил, вот такое:

**Sending packet data None**

**Reeived packet data**

То есть видно, что запрос ничего не отправляет.

Буду рад любым советам, как решить проблему. Спасибо.